# Regular expression 0.01-99.99

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying:

```
^-?[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$|^-?(99)(\.[0]{1,2})?$
```

but 0.00 pass

I would like to get result:

```
0.00 fail

100.00 fail

0.01-99.99 pass
```

Comment: shall `00.01`, `08.12` (*leading* zero), `99.8` (no *trailing* zero) pass?

Comment: This looks a lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905542/regex-for-positive-numbers-up-to-3-decimals-between-0-001-and-72-000) but with different numbers.

Comment: Why not just parse it (`double.Parse` or `decimal.Parse`) and check the value?

Comment: Going from what @ManfredRadlwimmer is saying, couldn't you do a check that it's less than 100 and greater than 0?

Is regex the best choice for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`^(?!0{1,2}\.0(?![1-9]))\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/FUdTZm/2)

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `(?!)` Negative Lookahead
- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `{n,m}` Matches between `n` and `m` times
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line